# Recycler view displaying only one item in a list

Tags: xml, kotlin

I am working on a small project where I can search up a city and it will return a list of cities with the same name but different locations. So far, I have implemented a search bar that can return a list of cities, however only one city from the list is being displayed.

Here is what I did

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var searchView: SearchView
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var cityAdapter: CityAdapter

    private val apiService by lazy{
        Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.openweathermap.org/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(WeatherApiService::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView)
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)

        setupRecyclerView()

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                if (!query.isNullOrBlank()) {
                    searchCities(query)
                }
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        })
    }

    private fun setupRecyclerView(){
        cityAdapter=CityAdapter(mutableListOf())
        recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            adapter = cityAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun searchCities(cityName: String){
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{
            try{
                val apiKey = "" //api key
                val cities = apiService.searchCity(cityName, 1000, apiKey)
                Log.d("API Response: ", cities.toString())
                updateCityList(cities)
            }catch (e: Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updateCityList(cities: List<CityInfo>){
        runOnUiThread {
            cityAdapter.updateData(cities);
        }
    }
}
```

adapter

```
class CityAdapter(private val cities: MutableList<CityInfo>):RecyclerView.Adapter<CityAdapter.CityViewHolder>(){
    fun updateData(newData: List<CityInfo>){
        cities.clear();
        cities.addAll(newData);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class CityViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val cityNameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cityNameTextView)
        val countryTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.countryTextView)
        val locationTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.locationTextView)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CityViewHolder{
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_city, parent, false)
        return CityViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CityViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val city = cities[position]
        holder.cityNameTextView.text = city.name
        val location = "${city.country}, ${city.state}"
        holder.countryTextView.text = location
        val coordinates = "Lat: ${city.lat}, Lon: ${city.lon}"
        holder.locationTextView.text = coordinates
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        Log.d("City List Size:", cities.size.toString())
        return cities.size
    }
}
```

List item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation = "vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/cityNameTextView"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:textSize = "16sp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/countryTextView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize = "14sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/locationTextView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize = "14sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In your list item XML, the `LinearLayout` has both `layout_width` and `layout_height` set to `match_parent`. This might cause each list item to take up the entire screen, showing only one item at a time. Try changing `layout_height` to `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small error as Iman Mohammadi pointed in the comments. The problem is `android:layout_height="match_parent"` (in `R.layout.item_city`) causing all the list items to overlap, it should be `wrap_content` instead.